# Tools for OAuth2 without client secret

Tags: rest, azure, oauth-2.0

I'm looking for REST tools which allow OAuth2 without the need to provide a client secret.
We need to access an API which has done his setup this way, but we can't seem to find a proper toolset to support this.
Neither SOAPUI or Postman allow this.

Do you have other REST tools which can be used for such a purpose?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont necessarly client secret, it s just an option depending on your authentication context.
Oauth 2 comes with 4 grant flows you can choose.
If I remember correctly the only one that needs secret is code grant flow. 
I suggest you check the other one to see if they fit your needs